# Allegro: How do I view the identifiers of all my components?

Tags: pcb, orcad, allegro

I'm using Allegro PCB editor to layout a board for a circuit that I'll be cutting out on a board router. In allegro PCB editor I just imported the netlist and I used quickplace to automatically place the footprints on the screen. My problem is that I can't see the identifiers on all the components, such as U1, U2, Q1, L3, C9, etc. Is this a problem with how I named things back in OrCAD or there some way of showing these identifiers in allegro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't have the layers that display that info turned on.  Take a look under component (or maybe package geometry), refdes and see if it's enabled or not.  Also make sure it's not set to black as the color.